# get the last word in body of text

Tags: regex, awk, sed, grep

Given a body of text than can span a varying number of lines, I need to use a [grep](/questions/tagged/grep), [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) or [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) solution to search through many files for the same pattern and get the last word in the body.

A file can include formats such as these where the word I want can be named anything

```
call function1(input1,  
               input2,    #comment  
               input3)    #comment  
               returning randomname1,    
             randomname2,  
                 success3

call function1(input1,
               input2,    
               input3)    
               returning randomname3, 
randomname2, 
randomname3


call function1(input1,
               input2,    
               input3)   
               returning anothername3, 
randomname2, anothername3
```

I need to print out results as

success3
   randomname3
   anothername3

Also I need some the filename and line information about each .

I've tried

```
pcregrep -M 'function1.*(\s*.*){6}(\w+)$' filename.txt
```

which is too greedy and I still need to print out just the specific grouped value and not the whole pattern.  The words `function1` and returning in my sample code will always be named as this and can be hard coded within my expression.

Comment: Are those blocks of code part of the same file? I.e. do you want to print the last word of a "paragraph" or rather of a file?

Comment: Yes, the blocks of code are part of the same file.  I want the last word in each paragraph.

Comment: I didn't realize my question lost some formatting so I need to clarify.  The lines using 'returning' such as returning randomname1, randomname2,  success3' can be on one line or 3 lines.  Also my functions will always be named function1 or I will edit the name so I want my search pattern to include this.

Comment: So if a "paragraph" doesn't contain `function1` you would like to print nothing?

Comment: Yes, correct, only those paragraphs.

Comment: This is not scientific. What is the definition of `a body of text` ? Not scientific since any programing block can contain extra blank lines.

Comment: To help you figure out what tools to look at for this and future problems: sed is best for replacing regexps on individual lines with other text, grep is best for finding regexps on individual lines and printing those lines, awk is best for any other text manipulation. Your current problem is text manipulation but neither of the first 2 cases I mentioned so you should be looking for an awk solution.

Comment: great tip.  I'll mark an answer when I can confirm.

Answer (score 5):

**Last word of code blocks**

Split file in blocks using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk)'s record separator `RS`. A record will be defined as a block of text, records are separated by double newlines.

A record consists of fields, each two consecutive fields are separated by white space or a single newline.

Now all we have to do is print the last field for each record, resulting in following code:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS="[\n\t ]"; RS="\n\n"} { print $NF }' file
```

Explanation:

- `FS` this is the field separator and is set to either a newline, a tab or a space: `[\n\t ]`.
- `RS` this is the record separator and is set to a doulbe newline: `\n\n`
- `print $NF` this will print the field `$` with index `NF`, which is a variable containing the **number of fields**. Hence this prints the last field.

Note: To capture all paragraphs the file should end in double newline, this can easily be achieved by pre processing the file using: `$ echo -e '\n\n' >> file`.

**Alternate solution based on comments**

A more elegant ans simple solution is as follows:

```
awk -v RS='' '{ print $NF }' file
```

Comment: It does return expected output. I've tried something similar using `RS = ""` but it didn't return first paragraph. A bit weird.

Comment: Works fine here, I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: Ok. With `GNU Awk 4.1.3` I cannot get it. But wait, using `RS=''` it doesn't work either in my version.

Comment: Perhaps you should try `RS="^$"`?

Comment: No luck. Maybe a bug?

Comment: And with the required keywords: `awk -v RS="" '/function1/ && /returning/ {print $NF}' file`

Comment: @Birei I suspect you are setting RS after the first record is read, e.g. `awk '{RS=""; print}'` instead of `awk 'BEGIN{RS=""} {print}` or `awk -v RS= '{print}'`. If that's not the problem then post your script and we can help you debug it.

Comment: @EdMorton: I declare it in the `BEGIN` block. This is the command I tried: `awk 'BEGIN { RS = "" } { print $NF }' infile` and it yields the last word of the two last paragraphs, not the first one. And as I said, using `Gawk 4.1.3` in `linux`.

Comment: @Birei it's got to be a problem with your input file. Maybe there's some control chars in there or maybe the "second paragraph" is actually separated by blank chars but no newline from the end of the "first paragraph" and just looks like it's newline separated on your screen. Try `cat -v -n file` to see everything.

Comment: @EdMorton: Yeah. That was it. I had blank characters. Thanks, master.

Comment: @ShellFish: I'm not the guy who asked, and I already had upvoted yours.

Answer (score 3):

How about the following awk solution:

```
awk 'NF == 0 {if(last) print last; last=""} NF > 0 {last=$NF} END {print last}' file
```

the `$NF` is getting the value of the last "word" where `NF` stands for number of fields. Then the `last` variable always stores the last word on a line and prints it if it encounters an empty line, representing the end of a paragraph.

New version with matches `function1` condition.

```
awk 'NF == 0 {if(last && hasF) print last; last=hasF=""}
  NF > 0 {last=$NF; if(/function1/)hasF=1}
  END {if(hasF) print last}' filename.txt
```

Comment: Great answer but you could simply do `if (last)` instead of `if (length(last) > 0)`.

Comment: `if (last)` would fail if `last` contained text that looked like a number and evaluated numerically to zero. Use `if (last!="")` instead since you are using `last=""` to reset it.

Answer (score 2):

This will produce the output you show from the input file you posted:

```
$ awk -v RS= '{print $NF}' file
success3
randomname3
anothername3
```

If you want to print FILENAME and line number like you mention then this may be what you want:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NF { nr=NR; last=$NF; next }
{ prt() }
END { prt() }
function prt() { if (nr) print FILENAME, nr, last; nr=0 }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
file 6 success3
file 13 randomname3
file 20 anothername3
```

If that doesn't do what you want, edit your question to provide clearer, more truly representative and accurate sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

This is the perl version of Shellfish's awk solution (plus the keywords):

```
perl -00 -nE '/function1/ and /returning/ and say ((split)[-1])' file
```

or, with one regex:

```
perl -00 -nE '/^(?=.*function1)(?=.*returning).*?(\S+)\s*$/s and say $1' file
```

But the key is the `-00` option which reads the file a paragraph at a time.

Comment: One failing of this and any awk solution with `RS=""` is that it cannot count "lines", it's now counting "paragraphs": you cannot get the line number, only the "record" number.